# Increasing and upper bounded function

Tags: limits

Show that if a function $f: [a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and bounded above, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}$ exists and is finite.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is bounded above, by the [completeness axiom](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L5.html) on the real line we know there exists a least upper bound for the function on $[a,\infty)$.

There are a number of ways to go from here, I will give you just one. (Since this sounds like a homework problem, I will try to make this solution nonstandard.)

We want to prove that there exists an element $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every increasing sequence $(x_n)$ diverging to $\infty$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(x_n)} = y$. Since $(x_n)$ is increasing, $f(x_n)$ is increasing, and $f(x_n)$ is bounded above by its supremum.

By the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), an increasing and bounded sequence converges to its supremum, we can conclude that such an $y$ exists and equals   $\sup\{\:f(x) \:| \:x \in [a,\infty)\:\}$

Comment: What if the function is increasing but not upper bounded?  Prove that a if function f:[a,∞) is increasing but not upper bounded, then lim f(x) x->∞ = ∞.

Comment: That is almost exactly the definition of a function which diverges to $\infty$. In other words, $\forall \: M$, and $\forall$ sequences $(x_n)$ diverging to $\infty$, we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $f(x_n) > M$